# sum between one form to another form

Tags: javascript

i make the sum between one form to another form and the number entered has a comma. I want to make an alert that cannot be input by letters. how can i do this?

input code

```
<input id="weight" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="weight" onkeyup="sum();" required />
<input id="runner" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="runner" onkeyup="sum();" required />
<input id="gross" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="gross" value="0" readonly />
```

this is my script

```
function sum() {
              var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('weight').value;
              var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('runner').value;
              var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue);
              if (!isNaN(result)) {
                 document.getElementById('gross').value = result;
              }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you are using modern web browser you will only need to do this:

```
<input id="weight" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="number" name="weight" onkeyup="sum();" required />
```

type="number" is sufficient.